# How to activate Markdown user snippets in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

User Snippets are an awesome feature of Code, however, I can't get them to work for Markdown files. A *markdown.json* file exists and is editable, but I can't get snippets defined in that file to activate (using Tab like for other languages). Is there a different activation method for these snippets or are they just not supported yet?

**EDIT:** Here's the contents of the *markdown.json* file just in case I'm doing something wrong there.

```
{
    "Markdown comment": {
        "prefix": "comment",
        "body": [
            "<!--- \n --->"
        ],
        "description": "A Markdown comment"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Open the editor
- Go to `File -> Preferences -> User Snippets`
- Select `Markdown`. The file `C:\Users\YOU\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\snippets\markdown.json` will be opened
- Paste your snippet into the file and save it
- From now on you can use the snippet in all `.md` files.

In case the snippet suggestion doesn't popup when you type "comment" then you should type `CTRL + Space` to force it.

Comment: Thanks. I think it was the ```CTRL + Space``` that made it register for me. That was the step I was stuck on. Thanks very much!

Comment: for mac users, the ctrl+space shortcut for autocomplete in vscode is option+esc

Answer (score 6):

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26108

in case you mean no popup quick suggestion, the link is the cure.

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": true
```

add this to user setting then you should be able to see the popup snippet suggestions

Comment: Adding this to user `settings.json` works:

```"[markdown]": { "editor.quickSuggestions": true }```

Comment: omg, i finally found a helpful method for me to use a snippet with a trigger, thx so much!!!

Comment: The settings seems to have changed to `"[markdown]": { "editor.quickSuggestions": { "other": "on" }}`. The toggles for comments and strings can usually be left off.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/1617#issuecomment-166999086

> Full extensions get auto (7x24) completion by default (e.g. latex, cake), some built-in extensions like Markdown do not.

You have to type CTRL + Space to force it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open VS Code
2. On the top left `File -> Preferences -> Settings`
3. In the settings search bar type `@lang:markdown quicksuggestion`
4. Change the value of `other` to `on` if it is set to `off`

Alternatively, after `step 2` above, you can search for `quicksuggestion` in the search bar and then scroll down a little. There you will see the
`markdown` section among others (like `dockercompose`, `dockerfile`, `JSON`, `jsonc` etc. in my case). Clicking the `markdown` section will take you to `step 4` above.